# How to legally sell installation of Windows 7 as a service?

Tags: licensing, service, distance-selling

I want to start a business. I will legally buy OEM keys for Windows 7 and then install them on machines and sell that as a service. Do I need some kind of license for that?

Comment: How are you intending to sell it as a service? Remote desktop?

Comment: How do you intend to buy OEM keys that are no longer sold to anyone and for which the OEMs have gotten a ban to reuse them years ago?

Comment: You will also need a time machine to go back to when Windows 7 was a thing

Comment: @Richard: Where I work, we have a machine running Windows XP and would pay a fortune to anybody who manages to upgrade it to Windows 7 without breaking the application.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Where do you work, and why would they pay a fortune to upgrade it to Windows 7 when they could just upgrade it to Windows 10 for much cheaper *and* avoid the risk of running it on the hacker's playground that is an end-of-life operating system?

Comment: @HashimAziz: Because the company that makes the software went out of business in 2001, and the last OS their hardware driver officially supports is Windows 2000. We have never been able to get the driver to work on Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, or 10. And we haven't been able to find a machine which has both PCMCIA and TPM 2.0, so we haven't been able to try 11. Even getting it to work on XP was a pain.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Isn't that what computer shops do? That used to be my job and we never had to ask a special permission to Microsoft. People would come to buy a computer and we would install the OS they asked.

Comment: @algiogia Unless you were installing pirate OSes, you would have had to buy a license from MS for each OS you installed - since it's no longer possible to buy Windows 7 licences, it's no longer (legally) possible to install Windows 7.

Comment: @HashimAziz: Rather importantly, Windows 7 is no longer included in downgrade rights of new Windows Pro licenses

Comment: @HashimAziz It was of course legal copies bought from wholesalers. My point is that you don't need anything special to install OSes, just legal copies. And that's what computer shops do already. So I don't see the novelty of the OP's idea, apart from limiting himself to a specific OS.

Answer (score 25):

You enter into an agreement with Microsoft.

But seeing as Microsoft no longer sells Windows 7 licenses, and Windows 7 fell off support long ago, your business proposal is dead in the water.

Comment: This is dependent on jurisdiction; in the EU, it is absolutely legal to buy and sell used Windows (7 or other) licenses. MS can't ban this in their EULA, this has been tried several times. OP's profile says they come from a city in Serbia, which is not part of the EU, but it's very much conceivable that the legal situation is the same there.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm - True, MS can't block the sale of these. But also, MS is under no obligation to activate new Windows 7 installations. After 30 days, an Unactivated Windows 7 starts to lose major functionality.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Serbia is not in the EU

Comment: It may be legal in some jurisdictions, but given the OS is not patched and has multiple critical-rated CVEs that will NEVER be patched, selling this is a lot like selling a ticking time bomb and therefore ethically questionable.

Comment: @WPNSGuy: Not activating Windows 7 is a boneheaded idea. Even under US law, that makes cracking it legit all of a sudden (copyright violation is still copyright violation but the tools themselves don't even look like contraband after that).

Comment: You don't need any agreement with Microsoft. If the OP manages to find legal copies of W7 he can install them just like any other computer shop.

Answer (score 14):

Whether or not you need to have a business license depends on local law (e.g. in the US the requirements are established by the city). Typically, software services do not require a service, but you would need to check with a local lawyer.

No license is required to install software for a person, but the software itself must be legally licensed. OEM system builder software packs are designed to be installed by someone else (not the end user), but you would have to vet your source carefully to be sure it is not pirated.